# how can i use cblas dgemv in order to multiply different dimension vectors?

Tags: c, cblas

I have a vector `sigma[40000]` and another one `u[200]`.

I want to use `dgemv` in order to multiply the first **200** numbers of `sigma` with `u`, and then the next **200-400** again with `u` until I use all of the numbers of `sigma`.

**I have something like this:**

```
for(i=0; i<200; i++)
{
    for(j=0; j<200; j++)
    {
        sum = sum +sigma[i*200 + j]*u[j]
    }

    z=...+sum;
}
```

**I want to make something like this:**

```
cblas_dgemv(CblasRowMajor,CblasNoTrans,1,200,1,u,200,sigma,1,0,return,1)

for(i=0; i<200; i++)
{
    sum=...+return[i];
}
```

The return value is a vector (`return[200]`) in which `return[0]=sigma[0-199]*u[0-199]`.